# JQ edit file in place after using JQ Select

Tags: json, bash, filtering, jq, edit-in-place

to edit a json file inplace with JQ like `-i` in sed I have found many solutions like

`jq ... input.json > tmp.json && mv tmp.json input.json`

This works, but I need to filter on my file, add some data, and place it back in the original. (ie. Update a specific object in a file)

My file contains over 1000 objects with **different `Element`**. I will always be using a filter on `Element`, I shortened for question. I have a sample file `original.json` ...

```
{
  "Element": "acton",
  "objectName": "contacts",
  "Path": "/contacts",
  "Scenario": "",
  "serviceLevel": "",
  "IBM": "",
  "Gap": "",
  "clientPhase": "",
  "parentPhase": "",
  "existsToday": ""
}
{
  "Element": "acton",
  "objectName": "optouts",
  "Path": "/optouts",
  "Scenario": "",
  "serviceLevel": "",
  "IBM": "",
  "Dependency": "",
  "Gap": "",
  "clientPhase": "",
  "parentPhase": "",
  "existsToday": ""
}
{
  "Element": "acton",
  "objectName": "subscriptionTypes",
  "Path": "/subscription-types",
  "Scenario": "",
  "serviceLevel": "",
  "IBM": "",
  "Dependency": "",
  "Gap": "",
  "clientPhase": "",
  "parentPhase": "",
  "existsToday": ""
}
```

I want to filter by `objectName` for `contacts` add some data to empty IBM field and save to the file

Applying the same logic to inplace edit the IBM field to `"Y"` on object containing `"objectName": "contacts"`

`jq 'select(.objectName == "contacts") | .IBM = "Y"' original.json > tmpjson.json && mv tmpjson.json original.json`

Now my file `original.json` shows

```
{
  "Element": "acton",
  "objectName": "contacts",
  "Path": "/contacts",
  "Scenario": "",
  "serviceLevel": "",
  "IBM": "Y",
  "Dependency": "",
  "Gap": "",
  "clientPhase": "",
  "parentPhase": "",
  "existsToday": ""
}
```

Expected Result

```
{
  "Element": "acton",
  "objectName": "contacts",
  "Path": "/contacts",
  "Scenario": "",
  "serviceLevel": "",
  "IBM": "Y",
  "Gap": "",
  "clientPhase": "",
  "parentPhase": "",
  "existsToday": ""
}
{
  "Element": "acton",
  "objectName": "optouts",
  "Path": "/optouts",
  "Scenario": "",
  "serviceLevel": "",
  "IBM": "",
  "Dependency": "",
  "Gap": "",
  "clientPhase": "",
  "parentPhase": "",
  "existsToday": ""
}
{
  "Element": "acton",
  "objectName": "subscriptionTypes",
  "Path": "/subscription-types",
  "Scenario": "",
  "serviceLevel": "",
  "IBM": "",
  "Dependency": "",
  "Gap": "",
  "clientPhase": "",
  "parentPhase": "",
  "existsToday": ""
}
```

It seems after using select I can no longer use the provided solution https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#general-questions

Comment: @peak I know has a knack for these questions

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your jq filter is not the one you need because `select` selects.  That is, it filters out the objects that don't match the selection criterion.

This jq filter should do what you want:

```
if (.objectName == "contacts") then .IBM = "Y" else . end
```

As for overwriting the file, many people who have access to `sponge` (part of the [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) collection of CLI utilities) use it, e.g.

```
jq 'if (.objectName == "contacts") then .IBM = "Y" else . end' input.json |
  sponge input.json
```